# Why doesn't "The Screwtape Letters" have the Saxon genitive in its title?

Tags: adjectives, saxon-genitive, book-title

I was recently asked a question regarding the book "The Screwtape Letters" by C.S. Lewis, and I am not sure about the answer.

The title of the novel does not contain the Saxon genitive "of Screwtape". Why is it so? He is the main character of the novel who writes letters to a younger demon. Should we see *Screwtape* (in the title) with an adjectival function, along the lines of "Letters regarding/about Screwtape"?

Comment: The letters are _from_ Screwtape, to Wormwood.

Comment: Compare The Dreyfus Affair.

Comment: The Quiller Memorandum, The Thomas Crown Affair, The Caine Mutiny, The Bourne Identity, The Eiger Sanction, The Princess Diaries... See e.g. [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/600626/object-names-as-objects-attributive-nouns), [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/411317/on-the-idiomaticity-of-attributive-proper-nouns-proper-adjectives-and-either-s) and dozens of other questions.

Comment: For what it’s worth, *Screwtape’s letters* could as easily refer to the ones he received and is in possession of as to those that he wrote.

Comment: [Why do we say _a hotel room_ and not _a hotel's room_?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/159545/why-do-we-say-a-hotel-room-and-not-a-hotels-room) compares the Saxon genitive / attributive noun choice to a fair degree. But here, _Screwtape’s letters_ is quite acceptable on one level, but loses **gravitas** for (as @Lambie says) an eminent collection. Note that 'the Nixon tapes' don't necessarily imply authorship.

Comment: 'does not contain the Saxon genitive "of Screwtape"' - "of Screwtape" isn't the Saxon genitive, which would be "Screwtape's". Was this meant to read 'does not contain the Saxon genitive of "Screwtape"' instead?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The Screwtape Letters is the name of a book.

Comment: Because English hasn't been Saxon in 1000 years.

Comment: @Lambie A book which comprises a collection of letters. Like 'Letters from Father Christmas', formerly known as 'The Father Christmas Letters'. On the other hand, 'The Beiderbecke Tapes' drama admittedly doesn't comprise a collection of tapes, but references a key element in the plot.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Last time I looked, children wrote to Father Christmas, he didn't write them...For every constant one can find in usage, there can be exceptions. But that tapes thing works the same way. I can't cover every single usage in English. You could have "The [x: proper name] Essays, Tapes, Sounds, Symphonies, etc. ad nauseum.

Comment: @Lambie I expect Edwin was referring to *The Father Christmas Letters* by J. R. R. Tolkien. The letters collected in that book are indeed (ostensibly) written *by* Father Christmas, *to* Tolkien’s children. [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Father_Christmas_Letters) (In fact I’m now positive that Edwin meant that book, because he quotes the first line of that WP article.)

Comment: @TimPederick That's fine. I was nudging the thing as his contradiction of what I said seemed a bit specious to me. (The tapes comment). It still works the same way for an entire litany of terms. In answering, you can't always hit every single little thing: I was concentrating on "The x's of y" versus "The Y Xs"

Answer (score 11):

- **The Einstein Letters**

[Auction of the Einstein Letters in The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2008/oct/08/einstein.letters.auction)

OR

- About **the Winston Churchill Letters** (1899-1951)
  [archive collection of Winston Churchill's letter](https://library.unh.edu/find/archives/collections/winston-churchill-1871-1947)

When a writer is referring to a collection of letters by someone, the person's name is usually preposed to the word letters.

Versus. Saxon genetive:

- Einstein's letters were often written in German.
- Winston Churchill's letters were known to number in the thousands.
- Shakespeare's letters were very eloquent.

Those are general statements about letters written by those men.

[Please note: I just made up those sentences but do not vouch for their truth, just the usage.]

The Screwtape Letters are a collection of letters by Screwtape.

Comment: You seem to need the definite article as well.

Comment: @simd Sure, right.

Answer (score 8):

"The Screwtape Letters" -> This is a very simple case of a noun - "Screwtape"- being used attributively.

The fact that the noun (phrase) is a proper noun makes absolutely no difference.

Compare
The **language** department /**information** technology / **beer** bottle, etc. etc. etc.

Answer (score 4):

As many have pointed out, it's a very common construction. It's taking a name (a person, place etc), and using it as an adjective:

- The Agatha Christie mysteries
- The Greenwich meridian
- The Reimann Hypothesis

The adjective describes the noun after it. It's effectively a shortened form for ease of use.

C S Lewis used it because it makes it sound like the language used by a detective / researcher / investigative journalist (who would deal with documents and other evidence), hence:

- The Nixon tapes
- The Rockford Files

It thus makes the book seem like an investigation or research journal.

I was never sure why C S Lewis picked "Screwtape". I assume that puts him in the category of the most evil of demons, responsible for making sticky tape tie itself in knots. It does seem a little lighthearted for the subject matter!

Comment: Agreed with this overall, but would the associations with detectives/journalists really have been salient for Lewis writing in 1942? I think of those as becoming established slightly later (like in the examples you give).

Comment: Lewis made up Screwtape on the principle that it sounded nasty.  He said so.

Answer (score 2):

The biggest problem here is that English has no synthetic case.

The preposition "of" is analytical without a case ending.

The novel gate-suffix derived analytically from *the Watergate scandal* is fusional, cp. *gamergate* etc.

Enclitic *'s* is definitely fusional. Thus, *yours* displaced *youren*. The formation by analogy is incomplete, so for example *own* remains in place (Old English *Godes āgen bearn* “God's own child”), genitive *-es* was removed (already in OE weakly inflected *āgenan* beside *āgenes*), accusative was merged into dative (OE *hine* "him") and it is widely recognized that reconstruction of pronouns and sentence structure is difficult (hence any mistakes in the above are my own).

Beyond this, Personal names may be subject to inflection. Henceforth, any inflection was either fossilized in the name (e.g. French *Disney*, *d'Isigne* "from Isigne”) or removed (e.g. *Frakfurt[er]*). This can become very confusing when the morphology of the name is less than clear e.g. *Walt, Walter, Dalt, Dalton* etc. (cf. [-ton](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/-ton), de.Wikipedia). An ambiguous case remains in *the Daltons*, *I stayed Hilton's'*, *at the Daltons'* (one might argue that the apostrophe is not pronounced either way, "James's Park", "King Charles's Island" but more often "King Charles' activities", *Jameson* showing it's Norse or Norman heritage, *Charles* being clearly Frankish in origin, Latin *Carolus*).

The Saxon Genitive or „apostrophic genitive“ is always *definite*, “Peter's car”, whereas indefinite constructions may use “of”, which can be used to show that the Saxon Genitive in English is not a functional case ending; e.g.:

- [[the king of England]’s horse]
- [one of [Peter's cars]]
- slightly ambiguous as a placename e.g. *King's Cross* (London, north of *Charing Cross*), *Kings Cross* (Sidney).

(de.Wikipedia: [Sächsischer Genitive](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A4chsischer_Genitiv#Linguistische_Besonderheiten)

It is also notable that the inverse, *# King [of] England['s]*, is abnormal in English except for a few higher register constructions, e.g. *the Era McCarthy*, often as Anglo-Norman heritage, *Attorney General* (but District Attorney).

Hence the question does typically never arise, if “the Screwtape Letters” ought to be genitive. Neither is there a denominal adjective, not *Japanese* but *the Japan files*.

> In grammar, a **noun adjunct, attributive noun, qualifying noun, noun (pre)modifier**, or **apposite noun** is an optional noun that modifies another noun; functioning similarly to an adjective, it is, more specifically, a noun functioning as a pre-modifier in a noun phrase.

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct)

This argument is often made in lexicography to avoid redundantly defined adjectives in the lexicon, since  every noun can be *attributive*.

---

The bulk of my answer is concerned with showing that *-n* would be historically correct, as it is in German following prime evidence of *Sonnenschein* "sunshine" (“from heteroclitic inanimate Proto-Indo-European **sh₂wen-,* oblique of Proto-Indo-European **sóh₂wl̥* (“sun”).” en.Wiktionary: [sun](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sun)).

We see that this impression is misleading and mainly ruled by euphonic principles as *Japan* < 日本 (Jp. *Niho​n*, Cantonese *jat6 bun2*; Malay *Jepun* etc.) has nothing to do with case, at all. Eventually, it seems that the Saxon Genitive is no more a genetive case. It only looks like one. In this view, the question for accusative, dative, or even ablative interpretations can be ruled out.

The remaining question should be, why *letters* presents as plural when *briefing* or *causa* do not, but the answer is trivial enough, in which *letter* is reinterpreted as count noun (it should be prudent, however, to attempt unconventional comparisons as long as a large part of the etymology remains gappy).

Anyway, Latin genitive ablativus postposition construction may show that the genetive does not mean what you think it means: *[urbis] causā*  “for the sake of [the city]”, indeed *for Peet's sake*, that is a pleeding *in the case made by Peet* (as often as his name is invoked he must have made a darn good case too).